# In sushi restaurants, what do you call the one taking reservations?

Tags: vocabulary

When we go into a sushi restaurant, there is (1) **one** who takes reservations - when the restaurant is not quite a big one, this one will be (2) **the manager** or its proprietor. What do you call this persons, (1) and (2), respectively in English? (For (2), some places call them just 'manager,' and some places call them according to their ranks, gwa-jang (section chief), bu-jang (department head) in my country.)

Comment: Are you talking about sushi restaurants in particular, or restaurants in general? What if, say, a spaghetti restaurant had someone taking reservations?

Comment: What if, say, a *cinema*, or a *car bodyshop* had someone taking reservations? The only likelihood I can see of there being a term specific to *sushi restaurants* is if some Anglophones adopt a foreign word in the first place. We did it for ***sushi*** itself, so that's at least a possibility.

Comment: Do you mean *taking reservations* as in *seating people (which may include a wait for a table)*, *waiting at table,* or *reserving restaurant space for future events?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any specific English nomenclature for employees at a sushi restaurant. I have not been to any sushi restaurants that refer to their employees by the Japanese name of their position, but I'm sure they exist in the country somewhere.

Colloquially, managers are simply called that -- managers. There is a difference, however, between "the manager" and the actual **owner** of a restaurant. Managers are in charge of the restaurant while the owner is not in the office.

To answer your main question, I think Jason S described it adequately -- the person that takes reservations and seats guests is called the host or hostess, depending on gender. Those who serve food to the guests once they are seated can be called waiter/waitress, server, or steward/stewardess.

Comment: I've not heard steward/stewardess applied to a restaurant. Have you? If you mean on an airplane, then those terms have been *replaced* by flight attendant.

Comment: I believe I have, it's fairly uncommon though, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely that would be the *host* or [*hostess*](http://www.hcareers.com/us/resourcecenter/tabid/306/articleid/641/default.aspx) — at least, this is what you would call the person at a restaurant who greets you and brings you to a table. (as opposed to the *waiter* or *waitress* or gender-neutral *server* who takes care of you once you're seated)

Comment: Yes, or *[mai·tre d'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maitre+d%27)* for a fancy restaurant.